# Which version of CDH using Cloudera Manager automatically Installs JDK1.7?

Tags: cloudera-manager, giraph, cloudera-cdh

I am using Cloudera Manager with CDH4.2.2 for my 3+1 cluster. On starting the installation with cloudera manager, it automatically downloads and installs JDK1.6. I want to use JDK1.7 with CDH for my convinience. Is it possible or is there any version of CDH which while installating Hadoop in the cluster automatically downloads and installs and successfully runs Hadoop with JDK1.7?

If yes, may I know which version of CDH is it and where do i get to download it from?

I want to work with JDK1.7 instead of 1.6 because i want to install Apache Giraph on CDH but it seems Giraph does not fit fine with JDK1.6 and needs the JDK1.7.

With Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JDK 1.7 is supported for all CDH applications as of CDH 4.4 and Cloudera Manager 4.7.

That being said, no version of Cloudera Manager 4.x installs JDK 1.7 during the installation (latest version is 4.8.2).  The only version of Cloudera Manager that installs JDK 1.7 automatically is 5.0.0.

To summarize:  If you want an automated installation of JDK 1.7 via Cloudera Manager, you need to upgrade to CDH 5, and CM 5.0.0.  Alternatively, you could upgrade to CDH4.4, and then perform a manual installation of JDK 1.7.